# Reversible Circuit Simulation (for classical tests of quantum subroutines)

Tags: circuit-construction, simulation

**Problem:** trying to implement and test quantum subroutines on quantum simulators I run into multiple challenges:

1. Quantum simulation is a *very hard* problem: a very low number of simulated qubits is supported
2. The toolkit does not offer arithmetic operations, often not even a structure representing numbers, e.g., a "quantum" integer. The simulators work on basis of distinct qubits only.

**Solution:** Assuming I am interested in translating a classical subroutine into a quantum circuit. The translation can be done without the use of entanglement and thus it would be sufficient to simulate a reversible ciruit (hence remove the overhead of simulating superpositons). Merely testing for functionality of such a translation does not require quantum effects.

**Looking for:** I am looking a tool(kit) that allows to construct and simulate reversible circuits for a large (a few thousands) number of (qu)bits. The toolkit should, if possible, allow the following:

- (Classical) simulation of the circuit
- Definition of subroutines (functions)
- Definition of structures (e.g. array of (qu)bits to represent an integer)
- Support a gate set that allows to construct arbitrary operations, e.g., Toffoli (no need to create superpositions though)
- Predefined (reversible) arithmetic operations (optional)
- GUI representation of the circuits, drag and drop (optional)

I would also be happy about a quantum simulator that allows to restrict to "classical" simualtion. Perhaps a quantum simulator is overkill and there are "classical" circuit construction tools that allow me to do this very easily (maybe VHDL?).

**Question:** Can anyone point me to simulators for reversible circuits?

---

I am aware of the extensive list of quantum simulators in [quantiki](https://www.quantiki.org/wiki/list-qc-simulators), and must admit, that I did not try all of them. However, I do have some experience with the following:

*Microsoft [Liquid](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/project/language-integrated-quantum-operations-liqui/)*

- Plenty example code
- can simulate $\approx 22$ qubits (on my laptop)
- can restrict oneself to stabilizer circuits (Clifford group) for larger number of qubits, but that does not give me Toffoli gates :(

*Microsoft [QSharp](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/quantum/language/)* Programming Language

- can simulate $< 30$ qubits
- allows construction of structs; has integer/ floating-point representations
- predefined quantum arithmetic

*Simulator [University Linz](http://iic.jku.at/eda/research/quantum_simulation/)*

- seems to allow to simulate larger number of qubits for certain problem
- poorly documented
- only (qu)bit level operations
- not actively developed

*revkit/ cirkit [RevKit](https://github.com/msoeken/revkit)*

- apparently simulation for reversible circuits
- has a GUI representation of circuits
- did not actually get this to run (only the gui)

*Drag an Drop [Quirk](https://algassert.com/quirk)*

- GUI cuircit representation
- allows to defined functions
- works very well for small examples (great tool!)

*IBM [Qiskit](https://qiskit.org/)*

- GUI circuit representation
- allows to define structures and functions
- no predefined arithmetic operations, but sample code for addition/ multiplication etc available on githut
- simulation limited to $< 30$ (qu)bits

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of the simulators in Microsoft Quantum Development Kit is [Toffoli simulator](https://docs.microsoft.com/quantum/machines/toffoli-simulator) which seems to do exactly what you want.

- It supports a limited set of primitive gates (X, CNOT and Toffoli gates, as well as other gates when their effect is X or identity), measurements in the computational basis  and `DumpMachine` to output the state of the simulator.
- It is a simulator for Q#, so all language features and libraries (including arithmetic) are available to it. The restriction on 30 simulatable qubits you mentioned comes not from Q# language itself but from the full-state simulator that is typically used with the Q# programs. Since Toffoli simulator doesn't create entanglement, it can simulate thousands of qubits - the default is 65k, but you can allocate more if you need.
- It is available with IQ# and from `qsharp` Python package using `%toffoli` magic command and `toffoli_simulate` method, respectively.

You can find examples of using it with Q# in [the Samples repository](https://github.com/microsoft/Quantum/tree/master/Numerics).

*Full disclosure: I am part of the team working on Quantum Development Kit.*

Comment: Works like a charm! :)

Not sure how I could miss that.
(Will leave this open for a few more days, maybe someone else got a solution they want to share too)