# What is a good program to practice using a quantum algorithm? Should I use Cirq or Qiskit?

Tags: qiskit, quantum-algorithms, resource-request, cirq

I am starting to learn about Quantum Computers and Quantum Algorithms. I also started reading about Qiskit and Cirq. I really like learning about them and hopefully I can be a Software Engineer with Quantum Computers. First though I would like to keep practicing and studying about them. I have a couple of questions.

What is a good program to practice using a quantum algorithm? Should I use Cirq or Qiskit?

Comment: Welcome to the quantum computing SE, pay attention that every answer to your question will be biased and there is no correct answer, therefor people may want to close it. For a first (and biased) impression, you can look on this [question](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/8221/overview-of-cirq-qiskit-q-ibmqcircuit-board-other). However, the two languages you have cited are very good, as they both provide very similar capabilities.

Comment: Hello and welcome to the community! Personally I mostly use Qiskit so I can't tell you much about Cirq, but there are a lot of good material to learn quantum information and quantum computation using Qiskit, the first being [the textbook](https://qiskit.org/textbook/preface.html) going through the basics of QC and the major algorithms, There is a lot of stuff but (imo) very useful.

Comment: There are also [the tutorials](https://qiskit.org/documentation/tutorials/circuits/1_getting_started_with_qiskit.html) presenting how to do pretty much everything using Qiskit, from building a simple circuit to directly learning how to send pulses to backends, and domains like error mitigation, optimization, ML, etc. This way, you'll learn quite a lot in quantum computing while doing some examples using Qiskit as well ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can start running basic algorithms like Grover's algorithm, Shor's algorithm, Quantum Teleportation Algorithm, and many more. That's how I started 3 months ago. Now, I am in a much better place. But, yes you need to ensure that you understand all these algorithms and don't just randomly perform these algorithms by copying from the Internet. If you don't understand the logic and working behind these algorithms, I would suggest the Quantum Computing and Quantum Information Book by Nielsen and Chuang. It is a really good book for a headstart in quantum computing.

Personally speaking, I use qiskit because I was taught by IBM instructors. But, what I think is as long as you know the logic it hardly matters whether you program in qiskit or cirq.

So, in short, you can start with anything!